# Weak convergence $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2([0, 1])$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Assume that $\|f_n\|_{L^2([0, 1])} \le 1$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure as $n \to \infty$. How do I see that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2([0, 1])$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: One way is via the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_%28Hilbert_space%29#Banach.E2.80.93Saks_theorem">Banach-Saks Theorem</a>.

Answer (score 3):

Take a function $\varphi\in L^2$, we have $\displaystyle \left|\int \varphi f_n -\int \varphi f \right|\leq \int |f_n-f|\varphi$.

for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have $\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$ for $n$ large enough, so $\displaystyle \int |f_n-f|\varphi\leq (1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon+\int_{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon}|f_n-f|\varphi$ and we just have to estimate this last integral, using cauchy-schwarz inequality :
$\displaystyle\int_{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon}|f_n-f|\varphi\leq\|f_n-f\|_{L^2(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)}\|\varphi\|_{L^2(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)}$
$\leq(\|f_n\|_{L^2([0;1])}+\|f\|_{L^2([0;1])})\|\varphi\|_{L^2(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)}$

Now $(\|f_n\|_{L^2([0;1])}+\|f\|_{L^2([0;1])})$ is bounded by assumption and $\|\varphi\|_{L^2(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)}$ goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity because $\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon)$ goes to zero and $\varphi$ is fixed. Note that this argument doesn't work when estimating $\|f_n\|$, and that's why we need the hypothesis $\|f_n\|$ bounded.

Combining all this we find $\lim(f_n,\varphi)=\lim(f,\varphi)$, so $f_n\rightharpoonup f$.